# Cannot Sign In With CURL In Rails Using POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I had a problem sign in into rails using CURL with POST method. What I've type in terminal is

**curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user": {"email": "admin@admin.com", "password": "abc12345"}}'**

but it returned some kind of html/javascript file in terminal. And here is my registration controller code :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    private

    def sign_up_params 
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
    end

    def account_update_params 
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password)
    end

end
```

and this is result i got in terminal for CURL request:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: localhost:3000
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 58

upload completely sent off: 58 out of 58 bytes
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 107406
X-Request-Id: afb62a3b-c193-4cda-be72-23c0af7d600f
X-Runtime: 0.208985
Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) is not blacklisted
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 15:14:29 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I hope someone can help me regarding this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the rails console say? What's the content of the body of the 422 response?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Try this instead:
http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/

---

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, add `:json` to accepted formats:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :json]
```

I suggest you also take a look at something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to test JSON requests.

Comment: thank you, it works. But it doesn't show JSON response. How can I returned JSON response. For instance like this one.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"response":{"user_id":2,"token":"6c54adfb9fd41e33738f3b3707e9726b"}}.

I already have token data in my db.

Comment: What are the response headers now that it's working?

Comment: I got this response : **<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/">redirected</a>.</body></html>** once I make a request with this command **curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user": {"email": "admin@admin.com", "password": "abc12345"}}'**.

Comment: try adding `-L` option to curl to follow redirects.

Comment: I got this using -L 
**<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Length Required</H1>
    WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) at
     localhost:3000
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>**